# Unity: Stuck, problem accurately telling GameManager when a round is complete (all enemies killed)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a lil issue with my game, on some levels (often randomly), my space arcade shooter get stuck. Player (ship) kills all enemies but the round doesn't end, and user cannot reach the next wave.

It happens 5% of the time, and I can't figure where the problem comes from. onEnemyRemoved should be completing a wave and trigger OnRoundOver there must a tiny problem somewhere that I cannot find. Headaches!

Sharing my round.cs script with you, appreciate any help you could provide! Thanks heaps! -> can dl the app here to test if you want -> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exodeploygames.spacefights

```
/// <summary>
/// Contract for any entity responsible for tracking enemies in a round.
/// </summary>
public interface RoundOwner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers enemy removed from round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy.</param>
    void RemoveEnemyFromRound(RoundEnemy enemy);

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers enemy escaped round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy.</param>
    void EnemyEscapedRound(RoundEnemy enemy);
}

/// <summary>
/// Holds all stationary enemies within a round.
/// </summary>
public class StationaryContainer : RoundOwner
{
    private List<RoundEnemy> m_StationaryEnemies = new List<RoundEnemy>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an enemy to structure.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Enemy to add.</param>
    public void AddEnemy(RoundEnemy e)
    {
        m_StationaryEnemies.Add(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes stationary enemy from round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy to remove.</param>
    public void RemoveEnemyFromRound(RoundEnemy enemy)
    {
        m_StationaryEnemies.Remove(enemy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes stationary enemy from round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy to remove.</param>
    public void EnemyEscapedRound(RoundEnemy enemy)
    {
        m_StationaryEnemies.Remove(enemy);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The current number of stationary enemies in the round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The enemy count.</returns>
    public int GetEnemyCount()
    {
        return m_StationaryEnemies.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the alive enemies in the round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The alive enemies.</returns>
    public List<EnemyHealth> GetAliveEnemies()
    {
        var enemies = new List<EnemyHealth>();

        foreach (var s in m_StationaryEnemies)
        {
            var health = s.myTransform.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();

            if (health)
            {
                enemies.Add(health);
            }
        }

        return enemies;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Responsible for round progression: starting and signifying to the GameManager that the round is complete.
/// </summary>
public class Round : MonoBehaviour, RoundOwner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked every time an enemy is removed.
    /// </summary>
    public Action onEnemyRemoved;

    /// <summary>
    /// Round types.
    /// </summary>
    public enum RoundType
    {
        Wave,
        Challenge,
        Boss
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The type of the round.
    /// </summary>
    public RoundType roundType = RoundType.Wave;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of enemies first spawned.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The max enemies.</value>
    public int maxEnemies { get { return m_MaxEnemies; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of enemies remaining.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The enemies remaining.</value>
    public int enemiesRemaining { get { return m_EnemyCount; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// All non-stationary enemies within the round. Important: enemies that are destroyed are not removed from this list. Null checks are required.
    /// </summary>
    public List<EnemyHealth> enemies = new List<EnemyHealth>();

    private int m_EnemyCount;
    private RoundManagement m_GameManager;
    private EnemyMove[] m_EnemiesMove;
    private EnemyShootStatusChange[] m_EnemiesShoot;
    private int m_MaxEnemies;
    private int m_EnemiesKilled;
    private StationaryContainer m_StationaryEnemies;

    void Awake()
    {
        m_GameManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameController").GetComponent<RoundManagement>();
        m_EnemiesMove = GetComponentsInChildren<EnemyMove>();
        m_EnemiesShoot = GetComponentsInChildren<EnemyShootStatusChange>();

        var roundEnemies = GetComponentsInChildren<RoundEnemy>();

        m_EnemyCount = 0;

        m_StationaryEnemies = new StationaryContainer();

        foreach (var enemy in roundEnemies)
        {
            bool registerAsStationary = true;

            var stationary = enemy.myTransform.GetComponent<StationaryMovement>();
            if (stationary == null)
            {
                var effector = enemy.myTransform.GetComponent<ParticleEffector>();

                if (effector == null)
                {
                    registerAsStationary = false;
                }

                enemies.Add(enemy.myTransform.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>());
            }

            if (registerAsStationary)
            {
                m_StationaryEnemies.AddEnemy(enemy);
                enemy.RegisterRoundOwner(m_StationaryEnemies);
            }
            else
            {
                enemy.RegisterRoundOwner(this);
                m_EnemyCount++;
            }
        }

        m_MaxEnemies = m_EnemyCount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the round. Calls each enemies respective begin methods. Delays starting shooting for 1 second.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartRound()
    {
        foreach (var enemy in m_EnemiesMove)
        {
            enemy.Begin();
        }

        Invoke("StartShooting", 1f);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers enemy removed from round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy.</param>
    public void RemoveEnemyFromRound(RoundEnemy enemy)
    {
        m_EnemyCount--;
        m_EnemiesKilled++;

        OnEnemyRemoved();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Registers enemy escaped round.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enemy">Enemy.</param>
    public void EnemyEscapedRound(RoundEnemy enemy)
    {
        m_EnemyCount--;

        OnEnemyRemoved();
    }

    private void OnEnemyRemoved()
    {
        if (onEnemyRemoved != null)
        {
            onEnemyRemoved();
        }

        if (m_EnemyCount <= 0)
        {
            OnRoundOver();
        }
    }

    private void OnRoundOver()
    {
        if (m_StationaryEnemies.GetEnemyCount() > 0)
        {
            var enemies = m_StationaryEnemies.GetAliveEnemies();

            for (int i = enemies.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                enemies[i].Kill(false);
            }
        }

        if (roundType == RoundType.Challenge)
        {
            m_GameManager.OnChallengeRoundOver(m_EnemiesKilled, m_MaxEnemies);
        }
        else if (roundType == RoundType.Wave)
        {
            m_GameManager.OnRoundOver();
        }
        else if (roundType == RoundType.Boss)
        {
            m_GameManager.OnRoundOver();
        }

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    private void StartShooting()
    {
        foreach (var enemy in m_EnemiesShoot)
        {
            enemy.Begin();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Too extense code to figure that out without debugging. Quite obvius but I woud Debug.Log() in the console the m_EnemyCount value  (or any other that could reveal the problem) so that when the issue reproduces you can check its value